# Access to the next value in a Twig loop

Tags: loops, symfony, twig

I have a problem to display the next line of a result in a loop using Twig :

```
// Arkiglass/ProduitBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
<?php
public function produitAction()
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p FROM ArkiglassProduitBundle:Produit p');
        $produit = $query->getResult();
        if (!$produit)
        {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('no such Product !');
        }
return $this->render('ArkiglassSiteBundle:Site:produit.html.twig', array(
            'produit' => $produit
        ));;
}
```

here is my Template

```
{# produit.html.twig #}

{% for pr in produit %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ pr.description }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {# display the next pr.description #}
        </td>

    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

I tried to use `{{ pr[loop.index+1].description }}` but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one possible solution to print two loop-runs in a row. The loop indexes (first the 1 based, then the 0 based) are modulo by 2, so in the first run, the leading `<tr>` gets rendered, in the second run the trailing `</tr>` gets rendered. And so on.
The first `loop.last` condition is to show a second empty column, if the last loop-run ends in the first column. The second condition is to close the row correctly.

```
<table>
    {% for pr in produit %}
        {% if (loop.index % 2) %}<tr>{% endif %}
            <td>
                {{ pr.description }}
            </td>
            {% if (loop.index % 2) and loop.last %}
                <td>&nbsp</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% if (loop.index0 % 2) or loop.last %}</tr>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
 </table>
```

Comment: I want to display Two Column in the same line inside the same loop not one column per line !!

Comment: Such things you should clearly mention in your question! I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Dude i did it brfore but i was just wondering if there is another way to do it a next methode or something like that but thanks anyway

Comment: I tried it with such a next approach, but there is the problem, that doctrine cursors (mongodb-odm for sure, orm ...) have no numerical index.

Answer (score 1):

This could seem a bit unelegant, but will avoid you the two loops.

```
        <tbody>
            {% set previousOption = false %}
            {% set nextIterator = 1 %}
            {% for option in options %}
                {% if options[nextIterator] is defined %}
                    {% set nextOption = options[nextIterator] %}
                {% else %}
                    {% set nextOption = false %}
                {% endif %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{ option.label }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ option.type }}
                    </td>
                    <td colspan>
                        <a href="{{ path('option_delete', {'questionId': question.id, 'optionId': option.id }) }}">Delete option</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {% if previousOption %}
                            <a href="{{ path('do_swap', {'optionId': option.id, 'optionId2': previousOption.id }) }}">&laquo; Boost up</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {% if nextOption %}
                            <a href="{{ path('do_swap', {'optionId': option.id, 'optionId2': nextOption.id }) }}">Shut down &raquo;</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% set previousOption = option %}
                {% set nextIterator = (nextIterator + 1) %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```